# How do I call an HTML page to a jQuery tab menu in the div section retaining all functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript and need some help figuring out how to put things together. I need to put my JavaScript image loop html page on my jQuery menu tab page. Here is my jQuery code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness /jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact-us">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="home">
    <p>A short paragraph about Overcoming Obstacles.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about-me">
    <p>A short paragraph about me.Banner advertisement that uses a JavaScript function to change the image every few seconds using three images.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-us">
    <p>My contact details.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
    <p>This is my gallery.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The part I need help with is the about me page. I have the image loop created with the page description and it works. What I need to do is call the About_me.html (named Brunson_About_me_rotate2.html) to the jQuery menu tab page with all its functionality. But I only know how to work with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, because that's all I understand how to do. It can't be done with Ajax, ASP, PHP, or SPRY because I don't know how to work with them and this is enough of a headache for me right now. And it has to work with the client side, not the server side. Also, this is going into a Dreamweaver page.

I have tried to put the loop code with text into the About us section of the Tab Menu code, but that doesn't work. Alternately, I have tried:

```
    <? include("./Brunson_About_us_rotate2.html");?>
```

(Because that's what the file name is) trying to call up the loop in the jQuery menu page About us, but that doesn't work either; all I get is a blank page. I'm VERY new to this whole thing and I barely know how to make this happen; it's taken me 5 days to get this much put together. I don't even know what options are available to make it work. Can someone help me figure out what to do? I just need these 2 pages to work together properly when the page is clicked. Thank you for your time.

After getting several options, thank you both for your help by the way, that did not work, I have been working the code around to see what I can do with it. I am posting the code just as it is now and almost what it should look like after it's uploaded to the web. Here's what I have so far:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Brunson - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness  /jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="home">
    <p><h2>What is a Life Coach?</h2></p>
    <p>A life coach is someone who is an advocate for you in reaching a higher level of understanding<br /> 
    and being the best person you can be in whatever area of your life you decide you need improvement in.</p> 
    <p><h2>What does a Life Coach do?</h2></p>
    <p>A Life Coach assists you in identifying those areas in your life that you would like to change.<br /> 
    Once those areas are determined, the process of creating the life you truly can begin.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pictureArchive= ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg'];

    window.onload=function() {
    var o=document.createElement('img');
    o.setAttribute('id', 'image');
    o.setAttribute('src', pictureArchive[0]);
    o.setAttribute('alt', '');
    document.body.appendChild(o);
    rotate(pictureArchive.length);
    }

    function rotate(idx) {
    if(idx>=pictureArchive.length) {
    idx=0;
        }
    document.getElementById('image').src=pictureArchive[idx++];
    timerID=setTimeout('rotate('+idx+')', 4000);
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>
    <p>I became a Life Coach so I could reach more people and make changes in more lives than I was 
    able to do when I limited myself to my Alternative Therapies Business. By choosing to take the 
    limits I placed on myself off, I have created abundance in my life and create more value than I 
    was able to do before. The school I chose to get my Life Coach Certification from was QSCA because 
    they have the same beliefs that I do. Living the Universal Laws, living my life with integrity, 
    being the best that I can be, and ascending to higher levels of awareness and consciousness allows 
    me to help others overcome negative behaviors and limited thinking patterns. Helping others this 
    way allows me to create a reality that is past the negativeness we have been living with.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
    <p>My contact details. Form asking for name, email address, and a message. The form will have an unselected radio button array that includes a yes or no response. All fields required. Validation of all fields is a must. Email address must be present and match</p>
    <p>the criteria for a legitimate e-mail address (using regular expressions). The submit button must call a validation routine; and when the user has filled in all information correctly, the page will display a thank you message and clear the form. The ehank you message can be s separate page, or it can be displayed on the same page.</p>
    <p>Are you ready to make a change in your life right now? Yes No</p>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery">
    <p>Once you make a choice to make a change, old limiting beliefs seem to just fade away.</p>
    <p>As nature abhors a vacuum, unlimited beliefs seem to jump to the fore.</p>
    <p>Where once there was nothing but limits, suddenly everything is possible.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I got with the code ya'll gave me was a blank about page, a page with a box that's window scrolled up and down and side to side and had an error message in it that said IE could not open webpage, and the last code gave me that code on the browser page. So I started just trying to play with the code and see what I could get to work. I almost have what I need. And yes, I do realize that some of the code is not placed correctly, but when I placed it correctly, the images didn't show up at all on any of the pages.

The only problem with the way this is, is that the images are on all the pages; they are just supposed to be on the About page. I'm going to be putting a contact form on the Contact page and 3 different images that fade out, move, and fade in on the gallery page. Then ultimately, after I get done coding this in NotePad and checking it in the browsers to make sure it works, this "page" with all this content included, will go in Dreamweaver that will have the esthetics attached, external links, a clock and then get uploaded. So, does anyone have any ideas as to what I should try next?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you made the php - tag not correct.

```
<?php include("../Brunson_About_us_rotate2.html"); ?>
```

And you also must put two points to get to the parent directory.

Comment: thank you for your response, however that code doesn't work either. If the code is php, that is not going to work on my page. At this point, nothing is on Dreamweaver, it's all being coded with just NotePad and checking the code by opening it in a browser. If it doesn't work that way, I can't use it. Any other ideas, including new code that uses only HTML, JavaScript, or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax seems a very easy solution for this.
jQuery already has it's own easy to use ajax functions.
One of them being `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#about-me').load('../Brunson_About_us_rotate2.html');
```

Another option would be `iframe`

```
<div id="about-me">
    <iframe src="../Brunson_About_us_rotate2.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: thanks for your response, but it can't be Ajax. Only HTTP, jQuery, or JavaScript.

Comment: You can only get the contents of a `html` page using an `Ajax` request or with `PHP`. Any specific reasons why you can't use Ajax? Another option may be using an `<iframe>` to display the document (but it has it's own restrictions)